# using recursion to reverse order of number in python

Tags: python, recursion

How would I use recursion to reverse the order of numbers. I have no idea where to even start off. Could someone help me a bit  here.
For example input =1,2,3,4
            output=4,3,2,1

I've tried and this is what I've got, but it's still not working.

```
def reverseDisplay(number):
    new_list=" "
    if len(number)==1:
            new_list=number
    else:
            new_list=reverseDisplay(number[1:]) + number[0] + " "
            return new_list    

def main():
    number=float(input("Enter a number :"))
    print(reverseDisplay(number))
main()
```

Comment: Your question lacks detail. What do you mean by "revere order of the number"? You mean reverse a list of integers? Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: No need for recursion, just use `list.reverse`.

Comment: http://www.learnpython.org/

Comment: i meant reverse order of integers. And im new to python trying to learn all this stuff

Comment: `def reverse(l): return reverse(l[1:]) + [l[0]] if l else []`

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: "reverse order of integers" is ambiguous. Do you mean, "how do I reverse the order of a list of integers?" or, "How do I reverse the order of digits in an integer"?

Answer (score 4):

The reasoning goes like this:

1. if the list is empty, rev([]) is also [] - this is called the "base case"
2. otherwise, reverse the rest (the list except the first element) and append the first element to that

so that

```
  rev ([1, 2, 3, 4])
= rev (   [2, 3, 4])                   + [1]
= rev (      [3, 4])             + [2] + [1]
= rev (         [4])       + [3] + [2] + [1]
= rev (          []) + [4] + [3] + [2] + [1]
=                []  + [4] + [3] + [2] + [1]
```

or, in Python

```
def rev(lst):
    if lst: # list is not empty
        return rev(lst[1:])+[lst[0]]
    else:   # list is empty
        return []
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 3,

```
def revRecur(n,ro=0):
if n//10==0:
    return (ro*10)+n
else:
    return revRecur(n//10,(10*ro)+(n%10))

print(revRecur(12345))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method to take a number or list. If the length of that parameter is one, return the number, if not call the same method with the list without the first digit. Then return whatever that call returns plus the first digit appended to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so I won't really give a full solution, but I'll provide a way to get there. If the numbers are being taken in as a list, then we can break down our solution as such:

```
if rest(lst).length == 0: #Check to see if we're down the first item
    return lst
else: #We need to break the list down some more
    return "call the method again on the rest of the list" + [first(lst)]
```

1. Break down the list into individual values
2. When we get down to a single item, start building the list back up (Base Case)

With Python, using  `stuff + [item]` will concatenate lists together (so long as "stuff" is another list). The else block above will call the recursive function to break down the list, and as it begins to return up the recursive dive, it will concatenate on the first item in the list in reverse order. This return up the dive occurs when the you get down to the singleton list, which the if block catches.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous.  People don't know if you mean to reverse a list of integers or a string of digits (since you are using `input`, I think it is the later).

However, I made a solution for each, so you can pick whichever you want:

```
>>> # For the list
>>> def rev(l):
...     return l and rev(l[1:]) + [l[0]]
...
>>> rev([1, 2, 3, 4])
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> rev([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
>>> # For the digits
>>> def rev(n):
...     return n and rev(n[1:]) + n[0]
...
>>> rev('123')
'321'
>>> rev('123456789')
'987654321'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def revr(n,r=0):
    if n==0:
        return r
    else :
        r=(r*10)+n%10
        return revr(n//10,r)
```